# Adding base64encoded file using form-data (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, form-data

I looking to use the form-data nodejs module to build up a multipart/form-data request. My HTTP endpoint I am posting to requires a file.

My "file" I want to attach is actually a base64encoded version of the file. I have the filename separately that I can use.

Looking at the form-data module - it looks like from the examples it relies on the file either being returned from fs or a request; is it possible to use options (field, value, options ) to make it accept either the base64encoded version of the file or do I need to decode it first? Ultimately the multipart is encoded anyway, or at least it can be.

Answer (score 0):

```
var upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage({}) })

app.post('/', upload.single('test'), function (req, res, next) {
  var raw = new Buffer(req.file.buffer.toString(), 'base64')

  fs.writeFile('/tmp/upload.png', raw, function (err) {
    if (err) return next(err)

    res.end('Success!')
  })
})
```

does this help ?

file name u can get from req.params or req.query.param , anywhere